# How to make these divs responsive for any devices?

Tags: html, css

hi I've written a few line code for a drum pad online website, now I waana make them responsive for any device screen. how can I make them?

here is my codes :

```css
.btn {
    
            background-color: #6775a3;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 23px 40px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: solid rgb(41, 41, 43) 1.5px;
            border-radius: 14px;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
            margin: 210px 0px 0px 530px;
            position: relative;
            
        }
    
        .btn:hover {
    
            background-color: #2c2f52;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    }
    
        .btn:active {
            background-color: #3f445c;
            box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
            transform: translateY(4px);
    }
        body {
    
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #475b6d, #091229);
    
        }
    
        #kick {
    
            padding: 23px 52px 23px 45px;
        }
    
        #snare {
    
            margin-left: 207px;
    
        }
        
        #hihat {
    
            margin-top: 100px
    
        }
    
        #crash {
    
            margin-left: 200px;
    
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Drumpad Game By Salbarno Studio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
            <script>
    
            </script>
        
        <button class="btn" id="kick">
            Kick
        </button>
    
        <button class="btn" id="snare">
            Snare
        </button>
    
        <button class="btn" id="hihat">
            HI-Hat
        </button>
    
        <button class="btn" id="crash">
            Crash
        </button>
    
    
 
          
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'd be thankful if you guys help me figure it out.
It's been a while I'm looking towards an answer for this code.
I've tried every method that may come to your mind except the "@media.." method and they did'nt work for the situation

Comment: you can use percentages % in the parent element

Comment: it loses its discipline

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap them inside a parent div

```
<div class = "parent">
   <button class="btn" id="kick">
        Kick
    </button>

    <button class="btn" id="snare">
        Snare
    </button>

    <button class="btn" id="hihat">
        HI-Hat
    </button>

    <button class="btn" id="crash">
        Crash
    </button>
</div>
```

And then set its style to:

```
. parent {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: If smth wrong - just tell me, perhaps i've understood the question wrong.

Comment: its not helpful, it changes its whole discipline, becomes a chaos

Answer (score 0):

Try with % value

```css
.btn {
    
            background-color: #6775a3;
            border: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 23px 40px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            border: solid rgb(41, 41, 43) 1.5px;
            border-radius: 14px;
            transition-duration: 0.3s;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
            margin: 30% 0 0 80%;
            position: relative;
            
        }
    
        .btn:hover {
    
            background-color: #2c2f52;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    }
    
        .btn:active {
            background-color: #3f445c;
            box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
            transform: translateY(4px);
    }
        body {
    
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #475b6d, #091229);
    
        }
    
        #kick {
    
            padding: 23px 52px 23px 45px;
        }
    
        #snare {
    
            margin-left: 50%;
    
        }
        
        #hihat {
    
            margin-top: 20%
    
        }
    
        #crash {
    
            margin-left: 20%;
    
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Drumpad Game By Salbarno Studio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
            <script>
    
            </script>
        
        <button class="btn" id="kick">
            Kick
        </button>
    
        <button class="btn" id="snare">
            Snare
        </button>
    
        <button class="btn" id="hihat">
            HI-Hat
        </button>
    
        <button class="btn" id="crash">
            Crash
        </button>
    
    
 
          
    </body>
    </html>
```